# Download bulk files drom Google Drive with adjusted parent Folder

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I would like to download from my Google Drive.
The folders structure is quite complicated. Here is the overview:

```
Parent Folder 1
--- Parent Folder 2
------ Parent Folder 3
--------- Parent Folder 4
------------ Parent Folder 5
--------------- Data
```

is there any script to download files with the folder structure like this:

```
Parent Folder 2
--- Parent Folder 3
------ Parent Folder 5
--------- Data
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past what you will need to do is create a recursive method.  First get a list of all the files on your google drive account.   Then sort them by the name if the file has a folder then create that folder.   Then Find all the files within that folder and list them.  You can preform a download once on the file once you have found the correct directory it should be in.

This is my example using C#.

```
public static void PrettyPrint(DriveService service, Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.FileList list, string indent)
    {
        foreach (var item in list.Files.OrderBy(a => a.Name))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}|-{1}", indent, item.Name));

            if (item.MimeType == "application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
            {
                var ChildrenFiles = ListAll(service, new FilesListOptionalParms { Q = string.Format("('{0}' in parents)", item.Id), PageSize = 1000 });
                PrettyPrint(service, ChildrenFiles, indent + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
```

My full tutorial on how to do this in C# can be found her [List all files](https://www.daimto.com/list-all-files-on-google-drive/)